# .NET Core Dependency Injection container not calling Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, console, idisposable

I'm at a loss here with why `Dispose()` isn't being called when the program ends. I wrote a console application to facilitate testing an Azure Functions App. One of the classes implements `IDisposable` but `Dispose()` is never being called. I expanded my example to see if a dependent service that implements `IDisposable` has it's `Dispose()` method called and it does not. I just updated to 16.9.4 this morning and target framework is .NET 5. Here's the sample code:

```cs
public class CustomOptions
{
    public const string Section = "CustomSettings";
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool UseHttps { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public interface IDisposableService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

```cs
public class DisposableService : IDisposableService, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing a disposable service");
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing some work");
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IConsoleService
{
    void Run(string[] args);
}
```

```cs
public class ConsoleService : IConsoleService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsoleService> _logger;
    private readonly CustomOptions _options;
    private readonly IDisposableService _service;


    public ConsoleService(IDisposableService service,
                          ILogger<ConsoleService> logger,
                          IOptions<CustomOptions> options)
    {
        _service = service;
        _logger = logger;
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Disposing {nameof(ConsoleService)}");
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Run(string[] args)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("The application is now starting {Start}", DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine($"The Url in the settings file is '{_options.Url}'");
        _service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<CustomOptions>(
                    context.Configuration.GetSection(CustomOptions.Section));

                services.AddTransient<IDisposableService, DisposableService>();
                services.AddTransient<IConsoleService, ConsoleService>();

                services.AddLogging();
                services.AddOptions();
            })
            .Build();

        IConsoleService service =
            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ConsoleService>(host.Services);
        service.Run(args);
    }
}
```

```cs
appsettings.json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "CustomSettings": {
        "Url": "www.contoso.com",
        "UseHttps":  true
    }
}
```

The output from the program is:

> info: ConsoleApp.ConsoleService[0]
> The application is now starting 04/14/2021 10:30:54
> The Url in the settings file is 'www.contoso.com'
> I'm doing some work

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Changes to get it working are as follows:

1. Add `IDisposable` to `IConsoleService`

```cs
public interface IConsoleService, IDisposable
{
    void Run(string[] args);
}
```

2. and remove it from `ConsoleService`

```cs
public class ConsoleService : IConsoleService
{
```

3. Wrap the `IHost` variable in a `using` statement or call `host.Dispose()`
4. Use `IServiceProvider.GetService<>()` instead of `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<>()`

```cs
    host.Services.GetService<IConsoleService>().Run(args);
    host.Dispose();
```

Comment: On Windows at least (last tested in Net Core 3.0), I wasn't able to hook application close events using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading` They worked flawlessly when built for Linux but not for Windows. I wonder if the application is simply being terminated rather than gracefully closing, or doesn't know that it's closing.

Comment: @Llama I'd expect such a mishap to be researchable in the "issues" pretty quickly? Did you contact microsoft with those close events?

Comment: @Fildor I didn't because I was building my software to run in Docker (Linux image) and only testing on Windows to verify if the event worked (it didn't, but did on Linux). I've added the event I used now, in case it can shed any light on OP's problem.

Comment: @Llama Thanks for the tip. Ugly but I used your suggestion to get a reference and explicitly call Dispose().  Temporary work around until something cleaner pops up.  It does work in .NET 5 on Windows.

Comment: @JonK, what if to mark IDisposableService explicitly as is `IDisposable` interface successor? I mean DI container probably does not know that `IDisposableService` must be disposed.

Comment: @Ryan That was one of the many, many things I tried before posting this question. All the articles that I read suggested it would "just work."  I assume it wouldn't make a difference IDisposable isn't on the interface since the DI container would look for IDisposable on the implementation. Since that's what memory is allocated to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example just using the ServiceCollection

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<Application>(); // your application which implement RunAsync
using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
await serviceProvider.GetService<Application>().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The biggest underlying issue is not wrapping the `IHost` variable in a `using` statement or explicitly calling `Dispose()` on `host`.  Doing either of these causes the container to get `Dispose`d of properly and all the objects it owns.  The second issue is using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<>()` doesn't register the object for clean up.  `host.GetService<>()` does.